# If I want to predict the next element in a sequence of numbers, what do I need to pass as second argument to Keras' fit method?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I'm trying to program a simple example to understand how LSTMs work. I want to take a simple integer series 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, and predict the next number. I've got a code, but I don't know what the second argument of the fit method needs to be.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM

df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Serie'])
for i in range(0, 10):
    df.loc[i, 'Serie'] = i
    
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range = (0, 1))
train_set = sc.fit_transform(df.iloc[:, [True]])

xTrain = []

for i in range(0, len(train_set) - 3):
    xTrain.append(train_set[i:i + 3, 0])

xTrain = np.array(xTrain)
xTrain = np.reshape(xTrain, (xTrain.shape[0], xTrain.shape[1], 1))

regresor = Sequential()
regresor.add(LSTM(units = 1, input_shape = (3, 1)))
regresor.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mse')
regresor.fit(xTrain, ???, batch_size = 1)
```

Can someone give me a very simple example of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the problem as a supervised one. Every sample contains the independent variable `x` and the dependent variable `y`. Based on your question, `x` contains samples of 3 timesteps and 1 feature. Start off by doing the necessary imports:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
```

Let's define some constants:

```
points = 30 # number of data points to generate
timesteps = 3 # number of time steps per sample as LSTM layers need input shape (samples, time steps, features)
features = 1 # number of features per time step as LSTM layers need input shape (samples, time steps, features)
```

A sequence generation from 0 ... 30:

```
x = np.arange(points + 1) # array([ 0,  1, ..., 29, 30])
```

Here is where we start setting the problem as a supervised one with `x`as a sequence of numbers and `y` as sequence of next numbers:

```
y = x[1:] # [ 1,  2, ..., 29, 30 ]
x = x[:30] # [ 0,  1, ..., 28, 29 ]
```

Put both `x` and `y` together for scaling:

```
dataset = np.hstack((x.reshape((points, 1)),y.reshape((points, 1))))
scaler = MinMaxScaler((0, 1))
scaled = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
```

Let's define the inputs and outputs of our model:

```
x_train = scaled[:,0] # first column
x_train = x_train.reshape((points // timesteps, timesteps, features)) # as i stated before LSTM layers need input shape (samples, time steps, features)

y_train = scaled[:,1] # second column
y_train = y_train[2::3] # start at the third element in steps of 3, for a total of 10
```

Model definition and compilation. I decided to make the model architecture a little more robust for "better" performance (see the results below):

```
regresor = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
regresor.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 4, return_sequences = True))
regresor.add(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units = 2))
regresor.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units = 1))
regresor.compile(optimizer = 'rmsprop', loss = 'mse')
```

Train the model:
regresor.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 2, epochs = 500, verbose = 1)

Some predictions:
y_hats = regresor.predict(x_train)

The results;

```
    real y      predicted y
    0.068966    0.086510
    0.172414    0.162209
    0.275862    0.252749
    0.379310    0.356117
    0.482759    0.467885
    0.586207    0.582081
    0.689655    0.692756
    0.793103    0.795362
    0.896552    0.887317
    1.000000    0.967796
```

As you can see, the predictions are close enough to the real values.

A plot of the results:

[image]

Note that for simplicity I performed the predictions on the training data set, the testing should be done on test data. For that, you will have to generate more points and split them accordingly (70% training, 30% testing). Also, you can obtain the values in the original range by calling the scaler's `inverse_transform` methods.

Comment: i've gotten an error when i tried do the inversed transform of y_hats. ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (10,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (10,2). why i've got that?

Comment: You have to make sure you pass two columns to the method. Since you are only interested in getting the values of y, pass the column for x with any values like 0s or 1s.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you some clue you can adjust in your program
In Friday results are 11, 30, 45, 52 ,56 and MB is 20.
How calculate 20 is following

```
 08
```

1. ```
      09
   ```
2. ```
         06
   ```
3. ```
      03
   ```

   2. 07
      The above matrix upper parts 01+09 * lower 02 equal 20 MB
      Combination of 20 is ( 10,02)
      (01,9)
      Another combination    (04, 05)
      You choose logical, relevant, efficient combination  of you applied above matrix then you can predict correct winning prediction

Comment: Welcome here! Please consider improving formatting of your answer